# Creating shift patterns

Tags: python

I'm a little lost and would love to help build shift buildings.
The work is carried out in an 8-hour shift and employees are entitled to three 10-minute breaks during their shift, which for convenience can start every ten minutes (i.e .: breaks can start at 08: 00,09: 20, ...)
It is determined that the maximum interval between breaks and breaks or between breaks and the beginning / end of the shift does not exceed w = 160 minutes) it can be assumed that W receives a value that is double 10 minutes.
**I need to build all the possible shift structures**.

I say this list indicates a shift, every interval 10 minutes

```
print(list(range(1,49)))
```

Example of one shift
A1=[2,3,....,15,17,........,32,34,...48]

I.e. break 1 in the first 10 minutes of the shift, break 2 after 150 minutes and last break after 330 minutes.

Thanks

Comment: Just start by taking the 3 breaks as late as possible. Then separately try to take each 10 minutes sooner. And only keep the solutions that respect the interval between last break and the end of the shift.

Comment: "The maximum interval between breaks and the beginning/end of shift does not exceed w" – but doesn't the example shift break that rule? It has a break right at the start of the shift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All shift structures can be obtained by performing a Exhaustive Search in three loops(a number of breaks) so that the condition is match.

```
work = set(range(1, 49))
w = 16
breaktime = []
check = 0
for i in range(1, w + 2):
    if i > check:
        break1 = i
        for j in range(i, i + w + 2):
            if j > break1:
                break2 = j
                for k in range(j, j + w + 2):
                    if k > break2 and k < 49:
                        break3 = k
                        if w + k > 49:
                            breaktime.append([break1, break2, break3])
    check += 1
shift_list = []
for l in breaktime:
    shift = list(work - set(l))
    print(shift)
    shift_list.append(shift)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just be lazy and use `itertools` functions here since the data is quite small. At larger numbers one might want to be more clever.

The `breaks` (and `shift`) results are zero-indexed for programming convenience (as opposed to 1-indexed as in the question), but that's trivial to adjust, and makes it easier to use e.g. `datetime` for actual times.

```
import itertools


def compute_breaks(
    *,
    timeblock_count: int,
    n_breaks: int,
    min_between: int,
    min_start: int = 0,
    min_end: int = 0,
):
    timeblocks = range(timeblock_count)
    for breaks in itertools.combinations(timeblocks, n_breaks):
        if any(abs(a - b) < min_between for a, b in itertools.combinations(breaks, 2)):
            continue
        if any(a < min_start or a > timeblock_count - min_end for a in breaks):
            continue
        yield set(breaks)


def render_shift(shift, timeblock_count: int):
    return "".join("O" if x in shift else "." for x in range(timeblock_count))


def breaks_to_shift(breaks, timeblock_count: int):
    return [i for i in range(timeblock_count) if i not in breaks]


for breaks in sorted(compute_breaks(timeblock_count=48, n_breaks=3, min_between=16)):
    shift = breaks_to_shift(breaks, timeblock_count=48)
    print(render_shift(shift, timeblock_count=48))
```

The renderings show breaks as `.`s and work blocks as `O`s, e.g. (truncated):

```
.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOOO
.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOO
...
.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.O
.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.
...
O.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOO
O.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOO
O.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOO
...
OOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOO
OOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOO
OOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOO
...
OOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.
OOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.
OOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.O
OOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.
```